# Exception Instantiating DBContext in EF Core

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Loaded EntityFrameworkCore v2.1.0 , EntityFrameworkCore.Tools, EntityFrameworkCore.SQLServer and Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions using NuGet.

Everything builds. Web App runs to the point of instantiating DBContext, then errors:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions,
>   Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext..ctor(DbContextOptions
>   options)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext..ctor()    at
>   Repository.RepoContext..ctor()    at
>   Business.AccountBLL.GetAccountListing()    at
>   ServiceFacade.AccountService.GetAccountListing()    at
>   AnnualMileageReport.FillAccounts() in
>   C:\Users\v\source\AnnualMileageReport.aspx.vb:line 23    at
>   AnnualMileageReport.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   C:\Users\v\source\AnnualMileageReport.aspx.vb:line 17    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

The file is present along with EF Core in the referenced path.

I have reviewed various SO answers to related questions but the modifications recommended have not fixed my problem. Versioning is correct. modifications to the proj file had no effect. I have removed and re-installed EF Core and dependencies with no success. I have removed bin and obj folders, also no success.

I've been beating on this for hours. Please help!

Comment: is there a build warning about missing assembly binding redirects? (this one can be double-clicked to add them). What binding error does [fuslogvw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) show?

Comment: Yes, there are warnings in build output, all of which are related to "EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers.dll" . Did you mean double click these? That has no effect.

Comment: fuslogvw shows nothing at compile time and nothing at run time.

Comment: See [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/613#issuecomment-354393350) for what I meant with double clicking. maybe you didn't set up fuslogvw correctly, all "Could not load file or assembly" type of errors will show up if correctly configured

Comment: @MartinUlrich, please turn your comments into an answer so I can credit you with the solution to my issue. You correctly identified this as a known mismatch between a .NET 4.6.x web app and .NET Standard libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be caused by missing binding redirects that are needed when using .NET Standard assemblies on certain versions of .NET Framework.

For libraries and executables, MSBuild tooling can autogenerate these. But for classic ASP.NET projects or web sites using web.config, this needs to be done by acting on an error message inside Visual Studio.

[image: Generate binding redirects for web.config]

Comment: You nailed it. Thank you. I did two things to get past this error. I followed the suggestions in the article "how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-binding-redirection" AND upgraded Visual Studio to the newest version 15.7.2. Now it works as expected.